# NSUrl FileUrlWith Path is appending " -- file://localhost/" at end

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play a video from url.
for this   i am getting the link from Xml parser.which is fine.

```
 NSString *path=[[self.items  objectAtIndex:videoIndex]objectForKey:@"link"];
```

i am assigning that path to NSURL fileWithPath as below.

```
    NSURL *mediaUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

While printing the mediaUrl, NSLog is giving "http://example.com -- file://localhost/
"

Why the -- file://localhost/ is appended to the url,Because of this video is not palying.
Any help Please.
Thanks.

Comment: try [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://******"]

Comment: and remove url form question if it is private url or belongs to your client....

Comment: i need to pass this url to MPMoviePlayerViewController.self.player =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];

Answer (score 5):

Change :  `NSURL *mediaUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];`

To :  `NSURL *mediaUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];`

As you are calling the `fileURLWithPath` it's appending `file://localhost/` to your URL string.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a bit old, but NSURL appends the -- file:://localhost if the string that you pass in isn't a valid full path string.

In your case, this is probably because you don't have a string with a "/" at the beginning (ie: "var/test" will have file://localhost appended as you've seen, but if you change it to "/var/test" you'll correctly get an NSURL with "file://localhost/var/test"

If you're trying to do a relative path, you could start with the "~/somelink" and then use stringByExpandingTildeInPath first to get the full path.